# Handle memory leak in android

Tags: android, garbage-collection, java-native-interface

I have developed a small application which used a shared library. When i run that android application in my device heap memory is increasing rapidly. I try to reduce that using gc() but that is not work for me. At one time am getting a message like Low memory no more background process and my app quit. How could i resolve this?

Comment: Are there any loops which allocating a memory/resources, creating a new instances of classes? Please show such loops code

Comment: Actually it is a live wallpaper application . In that am loading a video file as wallpaper , for that i compiled that video file using ffmpeg in the jni code and use opengl to draw the wallpaper. In the jni file am using the av_malloc function.

Comment: It is called from a video engine repeatedly in a renderer method.

Answer (score 1):

You have not only to use GC, but also drop references to the objects you do not need anymore - GC will not reclaim referenced objects.  You also have towatch carefully what JNI library does and also take necessary precautions in case it allocated memory of  start threads.

More detailed answer is not posssible until you say what you are using and post the sources

Comment: Actually it is a live wallpaper application . In that am loading a video file as wallpaper , for that i compiled that video file using ffmpeg in the jni code and use opengl to draw the wallpaper.

Comment: Is it really required to drop references manually?  I believe references would be automatically destroyed since execution moved out of the reference declaration scope.

Comment: It depends.  Execution scope has nothing to do with it.  At some time after onPause()  android framework would drop reference to your activity and  made it available for garbage collection ( and references held by activity will be dropped in turn makind objects eligible... ) But is you stored reference to activity on some static variable ( common error, since activity is also context which is needed virually everywhere ) it will not be reclaimed at all, with all the references stuff clogging your memory for ever